# Unable to create custom index on cassandra table for lucene search in Azure ACS

Tags: indexing, cassandra, lucene, acs

I had successfully deployed the `cassandra-lucene docker` image in `Azure Container Services (ACS)`. After getting into the container, when I try to create custom index on cassandra table,the below error occurs:

> InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query]
>   message="Secondary indexes are not supported on COMPACT STORAGE tables
>   that have clustering columns"

Note: The same image works fine in kubernetes on baremetal for index creation script.

Answer (score 1):

COMPACT STORAGE is a legacy feature that has no benefit after Cassandra 3.0, yet imposes a number of limitations ([see here](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/ddl.html#compact-tables) for details).

You can disable COMPACT STORAGE with the following CQL:

`ALTER TABLE mykeyspace.mytable DROP COMPACT STORAGE;`

If you're deploying a new Cassandra cluster I would highly recommend going with the latest version in the 3.11.x (or 3.0.x) branch unless you really need to use an older version for legacy reasons.